# ExceptionsManager.js:76 TypeError: (0 , _reactNativeReanimated.useSharedValue) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, camera-roll, getstream-chat

I am trying to integrate stream-chat-react-native in my react-native project and facing this _reactNativeReanimated.useSharedValue error when wrapping my navigation component with OverlayProvider which comes from 'stream-chat-react-native'

Error

```
ExceptionsManager.js:76 TypeError: (0 , _reactNativeReanimated.useSharedValue) is not a function

This error is located at:
    in OverlayProvider (at App.js:71)
    in RCTView (at App.js:70)
    in Root (at src/index.js:16)
    in NurseioApp (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
    in RCTView (at react-native-root-siblings/index.js:32)
    in RootSiblingsWrapper (at AppContainer.js:124)
    in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
```

below is my package.json dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@georstat/react-native-image-cache": "1.6.0",
    "@klarna/react-native-vector-drawable": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.7",
    "@react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll": "^5.7.1",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.10.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^4.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.5.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.10",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.2.3",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/toolbar-android": "^0.1.0-rc.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^12.7.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^12.7.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.13",
    "@stream-io/flat-list-mvcp": "^0.10.3",
    "apisauce": "^1.1.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.741.0",
    "easy-peasy": "^5.0.3",
    "expo": "~38.0.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "^0.5.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.0.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.2.10",
    "html-parse-stringify": "^2.0.0",
    "i18n-js": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lottie-ios": "3.1.8",
    "lottie-react-native": "4.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "native-base": "^2.13.13",
    "patch-package": "^6.2.2",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "~16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.11.0",
    "react-native": "~0.62.3",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1297.0",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.8",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^3.5.4",
    "react-native-draggable-flatlist": "^3.1.2",
    "react-native-draggable-grid": "^2.1.6",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-file-access": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.3.0-beta.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "2.3.4",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-in-app-review": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "4.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "0.31.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^2.0.13",
    "react-native-nfc-manager": "^3.14.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-portalize": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "~3.0.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.3.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^9.13.6",
    "react-native-tiny-toast": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^1.4.9",
    "react-native-unimodules": "~0.10.1",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-image": "^0.3.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.14.3",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "stream-chat-react-native": "^5.15.1"
  },
```

Previously I was facing error for 'RNCCameraRoll' so I uninstalled and again installed @react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll and after that I rebuild the app and facing this 'TypeError: (0 , _reactNativeReanimated.useSharedValue) is not a function'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out, please make sure to use dependencies that are compatible with each other.

You're using React Native (RN) 0.62.X, which is compatible with stream-chat-react-native (SCRN) 2.X yet you use 15.X together with react-native-reanimated 1.x.

We always suggest using the latest SCRN version and its respective compatible peer dependencies.

To read more about the version compatibility of SCRN and it's peer dependencies, please check our [docs](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/reactnative/#version-compatibilities).